# maven-bundle plugin and pax-exam: MANIFEST.MF does not exist

Tags: maven, osgi, apache-felix, maven-bundle-plugin, pax-exam

Following Situation: I am developing an OSGi Application using maven and maven-bundle-plugin. I want to run Unit Tests and discovered Pax-Exam and i find it quit suitable.

Here is my parent pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>de.hswt.oms</groupId>
<artifactId>workspace-parent</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
        <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Bundle Releases</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
        <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Built-By>Tobias Placht</Built-By>
                        <Bundle-ActivationPolicy>lazy</Bundle-ActivationPolicy>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Export-Package>{local-packages};version="${project.version}"</Export-Package>
                    <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
                    <Private-Package>{local-packages}</Private-Package>
                    <Service-Component>*</Service-Component>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>manifest</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12.4</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.ops4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pax-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <provision>
                    <param>--profiles=ds</param>
                    <param>--platform=equinox</param>
                    <param>mvn:de.hswt.oms/workspace-datastructure-core/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT@2</param>
                    <param>mvn:de.hswt.oms/workspace-command-core/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT@2</param>
                    <param>mvn:de.hswt.oms/workspace-facade/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT@6</param>
                </provision>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.org.junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<modules>
    <module>workspace-datastructure-core</module>
    <module>workspace-command-core</module>
    <module>workspace-log-config</module>
    <module>workspace-wsr-create</module>
    <module>workspace-datastructure-local</module>
    <module>workspace-localfile-create</module>
    <module>workspace-localfolder-create</module>
    <module>workspace-facade</module>
    <module>workspace-osgiframework-tests</module>
</modules>
```

I have created the module workspace-osgiframework-tests which contains a Simple Test case:

```
import static org.ops4j.pax.exam.CoreOptions.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.Option;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.Configuration;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.ExamReactorStrategy;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.JUnit4TestRunner;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.spi.reactors.AllConfinedStagedReactorFactory;

import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@RunWith(JUnit4TestRunner.class)
@ExamReactorStrategy(AllConfinedStagedReactorFactory.class)
public class SampleTest {

@Inject
BundleContext bu = null;

@Configuration
public Option[] config() {

    return options(junitBundles());
}

@Test
public void getHelloService() {
    for (Bundle b : bu.getBundles()) {
        System.out.println("Bundle " + b.getBundleId() + " : "
                + b.getSymbolicName());
    }
}
```

}

and the corresponding pom.xml

```
<project
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>workspace-osgiframework-tests</artifactId>

<properties>
    <exam.version>2.5.0</exam.version>
    <url.version>1.4.0</url.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>de.hswt.oms</groupId>
    <artifactId>workspace-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>..</relativePath>
</parent>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- skip plugin execution explicitly -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.exam</groupId>
        <artifactId>pax-exam-container-forked</artifactId>
        <version>${exam.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.exam</groupId>
        <artifactId>pax-exam-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>${exam.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.exam</groupId>
        <artifactId>pax-exam-link-mvn</artifactId>
        <version>${exam.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.url</groupId>
        <artifactId>pax-url-aether</artifactId>
        <version>${url.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.felix.framework</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I i run mvn test, everything works fine, but if i run mvn install i get the following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.546s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Dec 14 15:37:50 CET 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/233M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar         (default-jar) on project workspace-osgiframework-tests: Error assembling JAR: Manifest file: /home/knacht/development/repositorys/git/oms/workspace-parent/workspace-osgiframework-tests/target/classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF does not exist. -> [Help 1]
```

Any idea how to get rid of it?

Also this is my first maven project so if you have any advices please tell me.

Comment: A little off topic: if possible you should get rid of the apache felix dependency and replace it by an according dependency to the osgi core or compendium packages. This ensures you're not accidentally using non-standard functionality and leaves you the possibility to switch to equinox or any other container later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're new to Maven and Pax Exam, I'd recommend to stick to defaults as much as possible.

Using maven-jar-plugin and maven-bundle-plugin in parallel is likely to cause the conflict you're seeing. Change the Maven packaging of your bundle projects to "bundle" and let maven-bundle-plugin generate the manifest. There is usually no need at all to use maven-jar-plugin directly.

maven-pax-plugin is no longer supported in Pax Exam 2.x. You should use `bundle()` options in your `@Configuration` method instead.

For up-to-date examples, take a look at Pax Exam's own integration tests at https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.exam2/tree/master/itest/src/it/regression-multi.

Comment: I will give it a try on Monday. I am using the maven-pax-plugin to provision my Bundles into an OSGi Container and not along with pax exam.

Comment: Changing packaging from jar to bundle solved my problems. Thank you